# TYPO3 EXT: SB Portfolio (2) feedback

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I'm looking for at portfolio Extension to TYPO3 v. 6.1 FLUID/EXTBASE, and have looked at the EXT: SB Portfolio and maybe the version 2.

But need some feedback that know the extension and have played with it.

My question is.
Is it possible to changes the layout by adding classes/div's/span's, like TX_News ?
And is it like TX_News, to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do your own research before asking here. How can you do that?

Have a look at the manual:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/sb_portfolio2/0.0.2/

You will see that sb_portfolio2 ist an Extbase/Fluid extension. Therefore - as with all extensions using Fluid as templating engine - you can change the path to layouts/templates/partials as you can to it with "news".

If an extensions you want to evaluate doesn't have a manual, you can also install it and examine the structure. If it has a folder structure like
Classes/Controller
Resources/Private/Templates
...
it will most likely (not not necessarily) be an Extbase/Fluid extension.

So try to answer your own question in the future and get back with specific problems if it doesn't work out.

Comment: sry, but don't have the experience with TYPO3 like u, but U gave me some greate feedback so i know what to look after in the future, but i still think it's a "personal attack" to expect that all users inhere have the same understanding of a coding language, they haven't.

Comment: That's why I still answered your question; but it is important that you also understand the "mechanics".

Comment: true - but the only way to do that, "If u don't work with it daily". is to ask "a maybe simple/dumb question - for U" on a pro place like here, I am a professional soccer coach and I do not hit new coaches in the head, if they ask for something stupid as they should know, in my opinion - but people are at different stages in their experience.
But yes you write something right and that is to do some experience myself I also did that with YAM, that deleted/destroyed everything, so i needed to start from scratch again, so I am careful about what I install today and find it better to aske first.